# Does pinax apps support python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pinax

Does Pinax apps a support Python 3. Considering that it requires Django 1.4.x, that may be in doubt.
Can I use Django versions 1.5.x or 1.6beta with Pinax Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the issue on git here https://github.com/pinax/pinax/issues/63 the answer for now at least is "mostly".
As far as I know most developers are using python2 to be on the safe side.